# iOS Objective-C: CNContactStore unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate is extremely slow on some cases. What could be the cause for the latency?

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts

```
CNEntityType entityType = CNEntityTypeContacts;
NSMutableArray* allContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CNContactStore * contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactMiddleNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactOrganizationNameKey,
                  CNContactNicknameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
NSError *error;

if ([CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:entityType] == CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
{
    [contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:entityType completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted) {
            NSArray* allContainers = [contactStore containersMatchingPredicate:nil error:&error];
            for (CNContainer* container in allContainers)
            {
                NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:container.identifier];
                NSArray* cnContacts = [contactStore unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
                } else {
                    for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                        [allContacts addObject:contact];
                    }
                }
            }
       }
    }];
```

It seems on some phones the performance of unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate can be extremely slow while on others it is pretty fast. What may be the cause of the performance discrepancy? As far as I can tell the contacts on different phones aren't stored that differently, is there something else that could be the cause?